Problem getting cookies in the api routes of Nextjs
I am trying to get the cookies in the user api route for getting the userid , but getting undefined|null, even though i have a cookies stored in my browser, i am able to get the cookies in the server components though, is there a diff way of getting cookies in the api routes?
i have tried some methods but they didnt work out:-
export async function GET(req: NextRequest) {
  await dbConnect();
  const session = cookies().get('session')?.value;  //getting undefined
  const session_1 = req.cookies.get('session')?.value; //getting undefined
  const id = JSON.parse(session as string)?.id;
  console.log('id', id); 
  if (!id) return NextResponse.json({ message: 'User not found' }, { status: 404 });
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    if (!user) {
      const response: ApiResponse = {
        message: 'User not found',
        success: false
      };
      return NextResponse.json(response, { status: 404 });
    }
    const response: ApiResponse = {
      message: 'User found',
      success: true,
      data: user
    };
    return NextResponse.json(response, { status: 200 });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Something went wrong' }, { status: 500 });
  }
}


Hi! Can you please provide NextJS version? Also, you are using next/headers cookies right? And does cookies().get("session") return undefined too?

Hey, so the version is 14.2.2 and yes i am using cookies from next/headers. and  cookies().get("session") is returning undefined !! For your information, i m setting the cookies in the client side when the user is logged in . Is this why this problem is occurring?

It could be the problem. How do you set your cookie client-side?

`export const createSession = async (user: UserType) => {
// create the session
const expires = new Date();
expires.setDate(expires.getDate() + 30);
const session = await encrypt({ ...user, expires });
// save the session in a cookie
cookies().set("session", session, { expires, httpOnly: true });
redirect("/home");
};`

Is createSession called from a component in your code? Is it client/server component?

createSession is from server comp, and i am calling it in a client comp(Login), like when the user successfully logged in .

According to NextJS docs, you cannot use cookies().set() anywhere else than the server. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies#cookiessetname-value-options
I am not sure what would be the effect of using it in client. Fatal error? Silent error? You should try debugging that.
You can use server-only library to help https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/composition-patterns#keeping-server-only-code-out-of-the-client-environment

Hey , i have tried to set cookies from the route handler login which is perfectly setting the cookies in the browser, and also i am able to read that cookie. but in my another route handler user , i am not able to read any cookie, getting undefined.                              Login part----> // set the cookies     cookies().set("session", token, { expires, httpOnly: true }); // able to set.     const data = NextResponse.json(response, { status: 200 });     console.log("cookies-------------", cookies().get("session")); // able to read 
